# Asynctask losing reference despite being in retained worker fragment, trying to loop asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an app which makes rest calls and represents the data in a GridView.

The main activity uses two fragements, a UI Fragment and a retained worker fragment.  The worker fragment contains an inner AsyncTask that performs the REST calls.

Everything was working great I had no crashes etc, until I tried to do an update on a regular interval.

In order to perform the interval I added a handler.  The handler is a member of the worker fragment.  Within the worker fragment I have the LoadAPI method which calls the asynctask.

```
public void loadAPI(){
    final String myURL = "http://x.com/"
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            new APITask().execute(myURL);
            handler.postDelayed(this,10000);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is when there is a config change, my activity is destroyed, and onPostExecute crashes when it references the main activities listener.  But I have implemented onAttach in my worker fragment.  onCancel seems an ugly option, as multiple asynctasks can get called, and I don't have a named instance.  I suppose I could keep a list of asynctasks in the worker fragment and cancel them onDestroy (It's ok to lose the latest update) but I think I am doing something wrong here.  What is frustrating is the worker frag and asynctask were working fine until I did a continuous polling and I can't figure out why the introduction of the handler is causing this behavior.

My api tasks will take anywhere from 50 milisecond to 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retained fragments will not get recreated during config changes like rotations, but they will still get destroyed and recreated when system will kill your app because it is in background for example.

so to be safe you should at least:

1. Never put your async task inside fragment as inner class, if you want to have it inside your fragment class body, then make it static. Otherwise AsyncTask will keep internal reference to your fragment and will prevent it from being garbage collected, and whats more bad is that in onPostExecute you will access your destroyed fragment.
2. When creating your asynctask, pass a reference to fragment to it, and store this reference inside WeakReference<>, ex:

   `private WeakReference<DataFragment> fragmentRef;`

then in `onPostExecute`, before using fragment check if `fragmentRef.get()` returns non-null.

If you need continuous data updates, then consider using IntentService, or even WakefulIntentService. It will be slightly more difficult to report data updates progress from service to activity - but it can be managed with broadcasts. Also, if you want to do data updates from background then you will have to use service, together with alarms - then WakeFullIntentService (or regular service) is the way to go: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful for further reading.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.  The fragment in question is a retained fragment... I seem to be losing the reference to the main activity, not the fragment.  I have considered a service, but I really only want the updates to run while the app is active, and don't really need background activity.

Comment: Maybe my answer is not strictly relevant to the problem you have in your code, hard to tell - but this hints are helpfull in my opinion. In your question you say: `crashes when it references the main activities listener`, are you by any change keeping hard reference to your activity inside your fragment? If yes, then you might be refering to destroyed activity in onPostExecute.

Comment: Your hints are extremely useful, just haven't quite figured out what is the "proper answer."  Screen orientation changes are what cause the crash when I call the asynctask using handler.postDelayed()  I'm probably looking at the problem naively without understanding handler or asynctask.  The fragment updates reference to the activities callback onAttach.  inner class asynctask does call the activities callbacklistener but absent using handler.postDelayed() the dataListener reference seems to be properly updated on screen change.  Why would executing the task in a handler break the ref